# how to echo multiple DB results with one query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

If I were to echo the result of this query:

```
//Find membertype from community builder
$db->setQuery('Select cb_membertype From #__comprofiler Where id='.$user->id); 
$membertype = $db->loadResult(); //load the result from the query
```

I would use:

```
echo "Your member type is: $membertype";
```

I'd rather not use a new query for every variable thought since they are all in the same table.

I'd rather run a single query like this:

```
//Find all 3 from one query
$db->setQuery('Select cb_membertype, cb_2015vopac, cb_2015llf 
From #__comprofiler Where id='.$user->id); 
$result = $db->loadResult(); //load the result from the query
```

How do I echo the specific fields from that query when using the single $result variable?

Comment: Why API are you using? Is the result an array of all of the data in the table?

Comment: this is a joomla site

Answer (score 0):

First, let me just say that should should quote your values/columns/table names.

Secondly, if you want to get multiple values, you need to use `loadObjectList` instead of `loadResult`.

The following will do it for you:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);   
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('cb_membertype', 'cb_2015vopac', 'cb_2015llf')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->id));    
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->cb_membertype;
    echo $result->cb_2015vopac;
    echo $result->cb_2015llf;
}
```

So `loadObjectList` give you an object, then you can loop though it using `foreach` loop.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you should treat `user->id` as an integer and not quote it.